# (1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'user_id'")

Tags: python, django, base64

I am trying to update a profile by cropping the image, after cropping the image it is giving me a base64 string which i have to covert it into the image and store on the server as well as its url in the database. I am getting the image on the server but unable to store its url in the database.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(default='default.jpg', 
    upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          #super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
          super().save()
          img = Image.open(self.image.path)

          if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
              output_size = (300,300)
              img.thumbnail(output_size)
              img.save(self.image.path)
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

views.py

```
#profile view
@login_required
def profile(request):
    #if any changes POST data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_data = request.POST['image']
        format12,img = image_data.split(';base64,')
        ext = format12.split('/')[-1]
        imageObj = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(img+"=="))
        file_name = "myphoto."+ext
        #print(file_name)
        #Profile.image = data
        #Profile.save(file_name, data, save=True)
        #Profile.save()
        profile = Profile()
        #profile.user_id = request.user.id
        #profile.image= imageObj
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)

        #check if both forms are valid
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save() # if yes Save
            profile.image.save(file_name, imageObj)
            profile.save()
            #p_form.save() # if yes save
            messages.success(request, format('Your Profile has been updated.'))
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)#instance will show previous data in forms
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm()#instance will show previous data in forms

    # Send form data to the template
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

I am getting an error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'user_id'")
```

Anyone expert who can help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
Its Done 
This is views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_data = request.POST['image']
        b = json.loads(image_data)
        head, data = b["output"]["image"].split(',')
        binary_data = a2b_base64(data)
        profile = Profile()

        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save() # if yes Save
            profile.image.save('whatever.jpg', ContentFile(binary_data), save=False)

            t = Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
            t.image = 'profile_pics/whatever.jpg'  
            t.save() 

            messages.success(request, format('Your Profile has been updated.'))
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)#instance will show previous data in forms
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)#instance will show previous data in forms
    # Send form data to the template
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Refer this link https://vinta.ws/code/read-and-save-file-in-django-python.html if you want to know how to convert base64 image.

Answer (score 0):

Your Profile object is a 1-to-1 with the User meaning that the sole purpose, if I'm not mistaken, for you to create a Profile object is to add aditional fields. Given that, you don't require an ID to keep track of the profile, instead rely on the User model which by default comes with Django. Try removing:

```
profile.user_id = request.user.id
```

and see if that helps. Basically, somewhere in your database, you're trying to save the User object with an ID (primary key) of 2 again. A quick note if you want to save any changes you've made to your Profile object, do:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
user.profile.some_property = some_value
user.save()
```

Comment: I have removed this ' profile.user_id = request.user.id ' but now it gives me this error ' [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/adill/django_app/media/myphoto.jpeg' '

Comment: At what line does this happen?